# Eclipse Auto complete crashes for BoxLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Eclipse Auto complete crashes for Swing BoxLayout.

I type 'boxl' and Ctrl+Space. And nothing pops up. 
Not only that, auto complete stops working after that, and I'm forced to type everything or restart Eclipse.

I have observed this for some time, on different versions of Eclipse.

- Is there some feature that BoxLayout uses, which Eclipse cant handle?
- Have you experienced this?

I'm on Juno SR2.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse Mars and do not experience this problem. 
When I type I 'boxl' and Space it is autocompleted to BoxLayout.